# SaveAs on attachment object generates Error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, outlook

I am running a modified macro to perform the following tasks on an email in an inbox.

1. Isolate the attachments from the email
2. Open a new email to mimic exactly the previous email body to new recipient, without adding the forward information and signature etc.
3. Attach the attachments from the original email to the new email
4. Send the new email to the new recipient

In the steps to isolate the attachment, I am trying to save to an array as a temp location and then kill the attachment after completing adding to the new email.

At the line where the attachment would be saved to the array, I receive

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Code as follows for this segment:

```
Set myOriginal = olFolder.Items(itemNum)
Set myForward = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set myAttachments = myForward.Attachments

For Each olAttachment In myOriginal.Attachments

    If InStr(1, myOriginal.HTMLBody, olAttachment.FileName, vbTextCompare) < 1 Then

        ReDim attArray(0 To 0)
        attArray(0) = tempLoc & "Original Attachment" & olAttachment.FileName
        olAttachment.SaveAs attArray(0)

        With myForward

            'Make sure the attachments are in array format
            If Not IsMissing(attachmentArray) Then

                If IsArray(attachmentArray) Then
                    For i = 0 To UBound(attachmentArray)
                        .Attachments.Add attachmentArray(i)
                    Next i
                End If

            End If

        End With

        Kill attArray(0)

    End If

Next olAttachment

myForward.Subject = myOriginal.Subject
```

The error occurs on line

```
olAttachment.SaveAs attArray(0)
```

Comment: If you `Debug.Print attArray(0)` is the path correct?

Comment: It's [SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile), not `SaveAs`.

Comment: Thanks Comintern, I used the solution you and Evanzheng suggested and was successful with a few other tweaks.

Comment: Tim Williams, yes the path was correct upon testing - but thank you - it was smart to check to be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that the attachment object does not contain the SaveAs method.

You can try using the SaveAsFile method.

For more information, please see the following link:

[Attachment.SaveAsFile Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile)

Comment: Thank you Evanzheng, so there is no way to save it as the array?

If I save it as a file, is there a workaround to get it back into the new email, and then delete the saved file as to not cause glut in the tempLoc?

Comment: You can add a mail item as an attachment to a new message.
You can refer to the following link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/attachments/attach-an-outlook-contact-item-to-an-email-message